# Import from node_modules not recognized in es6 modules in browser

Tags: javascript, lodash, es6-modules

I'm trying to use lodash in my web application. I have installed lodash using npm in my local project.

I plan on using the ES6 modules in my code.

Here is my main.js file:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";

_.each([1, 2, 3, 4], (i) => {
    console.log('index each ' + i);
});
```

And I have included it in index.html as:

```
<script src="js/main.js", type="module"></script>
```

But I get the following error in the browser console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lodash".
>   Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

**Note:** I do not wish to use any bundling tool.

Comment: Why are you using a node module instead of a CDN distribution?

Comment: @RobertMennell , lodash is not the only library I need to use. I have other library dependencies which I doubt I would get on a CDN distribution. I even got a few internal libraries.

Comment: internal libraries should be served by you, yes, but if it's got a CDN you should use a CDN as it offloads and keeps you from exposing node_modules.

Comment: @RobertMennell Is there a link that would help find all/most of the JS libraries hosted on CDN? That would be helpful. If not, I can revert to manual search on Google.

Comment: https://cdnjs.com/libraries should have a lot of them, but other CDNs do exist and there are MANY lists

Comment: @RobertMennell thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't wish to use any bundling tools, you will need to provide a path to the lodash folder within `node_modules`, relative to the JavaScript file that you have the import statement in.

If you do not wish to use a bundler, it would also be worthwhile importing from the specific file, the function you need. For example:

```
import _each from '../node_modules/lodash/each'
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it did not work. Using `import _each from '../node_modules/lodash/each'` gave a 404 and using `import _each from '../node_modules/lodash/each.js'` resulted in following error: SyntaxError: The requested module '../node_modules/lodash/each.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Comment: Even tried this `import * as _ from "../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"` but got TypeError: _.each is not a function.
On `console.log( _ )`, I get an object of Module on the console.

Comment: shouldn't your import statement be `import _ from "../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"`?

Comment: @RobertMennell , I tried using your suggestion for importing lodash but that gives me the following error: "SyntaxError: The requested module '../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js' does not provide an export named 'default'"

Answer (score 9):

**As of 2021, please consider the following statement by [Márton Salomváry](https://salomvary.com/es6-modules-in-browsers.html) (Jan 2018):**

> Unfortunately even most libraries authored or published in ES6 module format will not work because they target transpilers and rely on the Node.js ecosystem. Why is that a problem? ***Using bare module paths like import _ from 'lodash' is currently invalid, browsers don’t know what to do with them.***

**And also the statement by [Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/) (May 2017):**

> "Bare" import specifiers aren't currently supported.
>
> Valid module specifiers must match one of the following:
>
> 1. A full non-relative URL.
> 2. Starts with /.
> 3. Starts with ./.
> 4. Starts with ../.

**And [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/modules-intro#no-bare-modules-allowed):**

> In the browser, import must get either a relative or absolute URL. Modules without any path are called “bare” modules. **Such modules are not allowed in import.**
>
> Certain environments, like Node.js or bundle tools allow bare modules, without any path, as they have their own ways for finding modules and hooks to fine-tune them. **But browsers do not support bare modules yet.**

Bundlers facilitate the use of "Bare Imports" which is not supported by the browser yet. Unless you bundle your code, I recommend using the solution proposed by **@Asler**. Besides, a lot of work is currently being done to study the implementation of "Bare Imports" in the browser, please follow this [link](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps) if you want to monitor the overall progress.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually you can't use JS modules on browser like that. These modules are for webpack or other bundler.

Comment: how to use them in webpack?

Answer (score 2):

Try module lodash-es

```
import each from '../node_modules/lodash-es/each.js'
```

Comment: All is good, until the module contains an import statement pointing to another package

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to import `css` file, make sure to mention `.css` in import statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can add your node_modules to the public dirs, so you can easily shorten your importing syntax from `../../../../node_modules/my-package` into `/my-package`

also, you need to specify the full path including the file and the extension

```
import mod from "/my-package/file.mjs"
```