# es6 async modules with axios - ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, babeljs

### Issue

I am testing axios within an es6 module and getting this error in the console when running the site in the **browser**:
 `ReferenceError: require is not defined` 
I know what the error means but I was expecting that Babel would transpile everything to ES5. So I suppose the problem is my setup.
**Remark**: This is just a test of async modules. Not trying to use the best possible code for production.

### Environment (inc. source code)

relevant info from `package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6"  
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2"
  }
```

contents of `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.19.2/dist/axios.js" defer></script>
    <script type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">         
      <div id="user"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`main.js`

```
import user from './components/user.js'

const app = async () => {
  document.getElementById('user').innerHTML = await user()    
}

// init app
app()
```

`user.js`

```
const user = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api')
  const rand_user = res.data.results[0]
      const template = `
         <div class="card">
            <img src="${rand_user.picture.large}" alt="rand_user" />
            <div class="card-body">
               <p>hello from template</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      `
  return template
}

export default user
```

Comment: Share your code as well

Comment: What line does the console error point to? I don't see any usage of `require` in your code

Comment: I have just added all the code including the transpiled one at the end. Require is in the transpiled JS.

Comment: @jet2016 ah that makes more sense now. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `@babel/preset-env`, you have to specify an option for how it transpiles your module syntax. If you want your `babel` configuration to target ES6 modules and to not transform ES6 module syntax, you have to modify your config to include this option:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "esmodules": true
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Refer to the docs [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules) for more information on this

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Now I have included the source code. In my setup I am already using `import axios from 'axios' `

Comment: @jet2016 no problem, but can you also include the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: I have also included the snippet to be run.

Comment: @jet2016 I just updated my answer which should solve your problem

Comment: Sorry, I had little time to check. Your answer regarding `.babelrc` solved part of my mistakes. I think I have only one conceptual issue now to understand regarding es6 modules. I am transpiling the code and still **axios** library is not included in the modules. I run the transpiled code in the browser and that is the problem I am facing now. This is the error in the console: `TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: axios` This comes from the above code in `user.js`

Comment: @jet2016 if you don't plan on using `webpack`, you may be better off including `axios` directly as a script in your HTML. Without `webpack`, your code doesn't know what you're referring to when you write just `axios`, since no module resolution is done. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558777/import-from-node-modules-not-recognized-in-es6-modules-in-browser) question for more info. You can either try importing directly from `node_modules`, or start using `webpack` or some other bundling tool

Comment: @jet2016 also [here](https://medium.com/@dmnsgn/es-modules-in-the-browser-almost-now-3638ffafdc68) is a good article explaining better why this doesn't work

Comment: All this fuss came from the fact that Parcel, my builder of choice, does not handle correctly `async` code inside modules. There are number of issues open on this matter.  I have also learnt that `àxios` does not currenly have esm version to be able to use it with import module syntax within the browser. So I ended up using an extra `<stript>` tag in my html with defer attribute and now works well. Thanks for your support awarrier99.