# Why is my Three.js file only loading a white screen on live server?

Tags: node.js, three.js, frontend, webgl

In the browser console throws this error ,
--Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".--
I am just a beginner in threejs.
Please help!!
I tried finding the Webgl2.0 compute flag but it is not available,
but when i check about:config ,
it shows
Webgl
webgl 2.0
both as hardware accelerated

Was expecting a black screen and a geometry figure exactly shown in tutorial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import from node\_modules not recognized in es6 modules in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558777/import-from-node-modules-not-recognized-in-es6-modules-in-browser)

Answer (score 0):

See the [instructions for using Three.js](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation).

You appear to be following "Option 1: Install with NPM and a build tool" but you have **skipped** the part about **using a build tool** and are trying to run the code directly in a browser.

When using `<script type="module">` directly in a browser, `import`s must be from **URLs** (and relative URLs must start with `/`, `./` or `../` as the error message says) and **not** just module names. (Note that just using a URL to three.js is unlikely to work as it probably imports other modules).

Node.js supports `import` from just module names. Browsers are not Node.js.

Build tools (like Vite which is used in the Three.js documentation) support using just module names. You failed to use a build tool.